# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name not found in context / Can't deploy on websphere

Tags: deployment, websphere, datasource, war, jndi

I'm new to Websphere and I  need to deploy my spring app (WAR) on a Websphere server, I configured the datasource, the jdbc and all. I'm having this error when I try to access to my app
*"Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [CORS]: could not be initialized"*

I'm having this exception :
*"javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name * not found in context "java:"*."
PS: ther is a space between "Name" and "not found" it's like I forgot something.
PS: the same war file is well deployed on JBOSS server.

```
[org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in *.*.config.AppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$151/0x00000000b4a75d90.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1841)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1249)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1591)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:708)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1451)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5478)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5694)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1341)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1353)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1246)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:641)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:984)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:531)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:352)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:966)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in *.*.config.AppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in *.*.config.AppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$151/0x00000000b4a75d90.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366)
    at *.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24.dataSource(<generated>)
    at *.*.config.AppConfig.entityManagerFactory(AppConfig.java:31)
    at *.*.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$0(<generated>)
    at *.*.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a15fd3c7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at *.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 144 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1970)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1377)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1220)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:149)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:156)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$$Lambda$164/0x00000000b4974d10.doInContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:156)
    at *.config.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:40)
    at *.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>)
    at *.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a15fd3c7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at *.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5097cc24.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 145 more

[9/16/22 16:10:59:578 UTC] 0000010d SystemOut     O   req=set&sessionVariable=com_ibm_ws_probdetermination_prefsTable&variableValue=none
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R   java.lang.Throwable
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:503)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.CSRFUtils.verifyCSRFTokenInRequest(CSRFUtils.java:78)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.ConfigFileHelper.isSessionValid(ConfigFileHelper.java:1106)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at _ibmjsp.secure._javascriptToSession._jspService(_javascriptToSession.java:158)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:579 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:220)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:984)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:531)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:352)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:966)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:580 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:581 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:581 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:581 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:581 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[9/16/22 16:10:59:581 UTC] 0000010d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

Comment: That suggests Spring is doing a lookup of “java:” and expecting a datasource. There isn’t enough info in the question to diagnose further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what informations you want me to share with you?

Comment: You said "I configured the datasource, the jdbc and all", so I'm assuming you're not using an app defined DS.  Please post the config for your DS and JDBC provider.  As Alasdair said, the error suggests incorrect DS config is not correct